# The long type is not implicitily convertible to ulong type.But when long literal is assigned to ulong it compiles without an error

Tags: c#-4.0

```
long x =90;
```

`ulong u = x;`

//error since long cannot be implicitily converted to  ulong

But, `ulong u =90L;`  //compiles in spite of 90L being of long type.

Can someone please explain this ambiguity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) ... "When you use the suffix L, the type of the literal integer is determined to be either **long or ulong** according to its size."

Therefore, "90L" can be implicitly converted to either a long or ulong but a long cannot be implicitly converted to a ulong.

Comment: That is good but why var h = 7ul + 9L;// no error
            var g = new[] { 7ul, 9L}; //error no best type found for implicitily typed array.

Comment: Same reason as above. 9L can be implicitly converted to either a long or ulong. For the array, is 9L long or ulong? From MSDN, "Array elements must all be the same type or implicitly convertible to the same type according to the type inference rules used by the compiler". If you have "var h = 9L'" what is the type of h? Once you understand why it is what it is you will be able to answer your array question.  I suggest looking at the CSharp Language Specification which explains. It's better if you figure it out with some clues instead me just giving you answers. Let me know what you find out.